# I do not understand what this small block of code means

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, ajax

so after reading a dozen tutorials and posts, I figured that '/todo/'+item is the URL that this code sends the request to, but is the entire URL https://MyHomePageURL + '/todo/'+item? but when I entered that http url, the page was invalid. I entered basically any possible http URLs before and after every request I made and only "http://127.0.0.1:5000/todo" which is the homepage worked and no other URL worked. (for example, when the value of item is chair, this -> http://127.0.0.1:5000/todo/chair should work but it doesn't). Also is there any reason why this Ajax request has to be specifically sent to that specific https:// URL?

the code I'm specifically talking about is from the file "todo-list.js"

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('form').on('submit', function(){

  var item = $('form input');
  var todo = {item: item.val()};

  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/todo',
    data: todo,
    success: function(data){
      location.reload();
    }
  });

  return false;

});

$('li').on('click', function(){
  var item = $(this).text().replace(/ /g, "-");
  $.ajax({
    type: 'DELETE',
    url: '/todo/' + item,
    success: function(data){
      location.reload();
    }
  });
});

});
```

and for broader context, here's the code file called "todoController.js"

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var data = [{item: 'chair'}, {item: 'flower'}, {item: 'bed'}];
var urlencodedParser = bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false});

module.exports = function(app) {

app.get('/todo', function(req, res){
    res.render('todo', {todos: data});

});

app.post('/todo', urlencodedParser, function(req, res){
    data.push(req.body);
    res.json(data);
});


app.delete('/todo/:item', function(req, res){
    data = data.filter(function(todo){
        return todo.item.replace(/ /g, '-') !== req.params.item;
    });
    res.json(data);
});

};
```

this is the main code that starts the app named "index.js".

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

var todoController = require('./todoController');
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.use(express.static('./'));

todoController(app);


app.listen(5000, '127.0.0.1');
```

another code file working this app named "todo.ejs"

```
<html>
   <head>
    <title>Todo List</title>
    <script
    src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"
    integrity="sha256- 
    CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo="
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="assets/todo-list.js"></script>
    <link href="assets/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" 
     type="text/css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>My Todo List</h1>
    <div id="todo-table">
      <form>
        <input type="text" name="item" placeholder="Add new 
         item..." required />
        <button type="submit">Add Item</button>
      </form>
      <ul>

              <% for(var i=0; i < todos.length; i++){ %>
                <li><%= todos[i].item %></li>
              <% } %>

      </ul>
    </div>

  </body>


</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you type the URL in browser address bar and press enter, browser will make a `GET` request to the server. If you check your server code (second file you have provided) that URL `/todo/:item` only accepts `DELETE` request. That's why you are getting invalid page when you access that URL from browser. But the URL `/todo` has both `GET` and `POST` methods defined. That's why you got `GET` response defined in server when you hit that URL from the browser.

Comment: ah... I see... so in Laymen's terms, "http://127.0.0.1:5000/todo/"+item URL does NOT exist right? or does it exist for a split second when DELETE request is getting processed?

Comment: It doesn't exists. Because there is no corresponding code in your sever js file. For GET request to work on that URL there must be something like `app.get('/todo/:item', function(req, res){ ...` in your server code.

Comment: I just added the entire code files written to give the full context and my code has `app.get('/todo', function(req, res){
    res.render('todo', {todos: data});

});` somewhere.

Comment: okay sorry but... I'm still confused why if '/todo/:item' URL doesn't exist at all, it still has to send the delete request to  '/todo/:item' URL. Can you tell me why? Why did the original code want to send the DELETE request to  '/todo/:item' ?? and how can you send a request to a URL that doesn't exist at all?

Answer (score 0):

It's confusing but as I understand you want to understand the code here are my thoughts, ajax is making an HTTP DELETE request over the resource (i.e todo/:item)

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'DELETE',
```

which at the server is received by the following the code

```
app.delete('/todo/:item', function(req, res){
```

If you run this in postman (not in the browser) with the appropriate setting you would be able to see it working. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. so... what I'm still confused about is that my code says `url: '/todo/' + item` which means that that URL has to exist right? but when I enter that http URL, it doesn't exist at all. why is that?

Comment: can you open Console in the browser window and check if there is any error. As it's an Ajax request you might find the call in the "Network" tab which will give you more insight about the error. ( also please check your backend server is running)

Comment: so.. I checked Console in the browser and this is the error I got: Error parsing 'integrity' attribute ('sha256- 
        CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo='). The digest must be a valid, base64-encoded value.